# Using PIVOT operator in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I used pivot like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT STUDENT_NAME,subject_code ,TERM_I_GRADE  FROM tablename
)
PIVOT
(
 TERM_I_GRADE 
  FOR subject_code IN (2001,2002)
)
ORDER BY STUDENT_NAME;
```

```
std_code Student_Name  subject_code    TERM_I_GRADE  
9        Kishan        2003            A
9        Kishan        2001            A
9        Kishan        2002            A
9        Kishan        2007            A
9        Kishan        2004            A

output 
-------------------
stdcode Student_Name  2003  2001  2002  2007 2004 
9       Kishan        A      A    A     A    A
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want output like this output 
-------------------
stdcode Student Name 2003  2001  2002  2007 2004 
9       Kishan        A      A    A     A    A

Comment: You are just missing an aggregate function in PIVOT.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  *
from    mytable pivot (max(TERM_I_GRADE) for subject_code in (2003,2001,2002,2007,2004)) p
```

---

```
+----------+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+
| STD_CODE | STUDENT_NAME | 2003 | 2001 | 2002 | 2007 | 2004 |
+----------+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 9        | Kishan       | A    | A    | A    | A    | A    |
+----------+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT YEAR_CODE, 'HAVALGA' AS School_Name,class_code,STUDENT_CODE,STUDENT_NAME,KANNADA,ENGLISH,HINDI,MATHS,SCIENS,SOCIAL,EVS from
(SELECT 
        YEAR_CODE,class_code,STUDENT_CODE,STUDENT_NAME, 
        SUBJECT_CODE,TERM_I_GRADE as TERM_I_GRADE
FROM    SRSDF_EXAM_TERM_I 
WHERE
      SCHOOL_CODE=1301  AND YEAR_CODE='2016-2017'

) 
PIVOT(MAX(TERM_I_GRADE)  FOR 
    SUBJECT_CODE IN (2001 AS KANNADA,2002 AS ENGLISH,
                     2003 AS HINDI,2004 AS MATHS,
                     2005 AS SCIENS,2006 AS SOCIAL,
                     2007 AS EVS))
         ORDER BY class_code,STUDENT_CODE            ;